# Batch looking up on website and take action

Tags: batch-file, web, respond-to

Is there a way to create a batch file that when it looks something up on a website, and find a picture, text or something there, that it takes action to it, like, when it found the pictures the batch should GOTO:Choice1 and when not GOTO:Choice2 ?

Comment: You can Use `Curl` or `Wget` to download the source of the page and then aplly a `find` against the downloaded XML.

Comment: Can you give me a short code on how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example :

```
@echo off
curl URL_of_Your_Web_site>File.xml
findstr /i "the string to search" file.xml && echo string found || echo string not found
```

If you have to make a LOGIN in the Web site you have to download first the cookie with your ID and Password.

Comment: Do i have to install curl on all computers that use this batch? Because i just see that you need to install curl to use this command?

Comment: curl no need installation it's an `.exe` : http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?download=curl_737_0.zip&PHPSESSID=08556dc20264adcaadf71c1ba53cdb4d

Comment: I tried to do it with my website, but i get an error, that curl is a command that does not exist

Comment: You have to download curl clic on the link in my last comment.

Comment: Okay, but does all pc, that run this batch, need to have curl installed?

Comment: Or like you say to be downloaded?

Comment: Yes, @tanckom that's the only way. Or you can integrate curl in HEXA in your bat and reconstruct it when you're bat is executed.